# how to create a new div of json response array from controller

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent

I have a case of wanting to create a div element based on the element div obtained from json response I checked in the console data successfully passed to view blade, the error is to fail add new element div based on json response obtained. Can anyone help?

**my code**

```php
public function getIDpotongan($id)
{
    $data = array();
    $list = PotonganPenggajianModel::where('nip', $id)->get();
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        $val = array();
        $val[] ='<h3> ' . "'" . $row['jenis_potongan'] . "'" . '</h3>';
        $data[] = $val;
    }
    $output = array("data" => $data);
    return response()->json($output);
}
```

**AJAX**

```js
$('#nama').on('change', function () {
    var optionText = $("#nama option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo url('/'); ?>" + "/getidpotongan/" + optionText,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#potonganku').html(data);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {}
    });
});
```

blade

```
 <div id="potonganku" class="form-group row"> </div>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: share the code of your blade file.
As well as where did you put your Ajax code? In the same file or separate its a separate blade?

Comment: ihave edited my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way in that case is to build markup on the client side. Return raw JSON data from controller, and then build HTML via JS.

**Controller:**

```php
public function getIDpotongan($id)
{
    return response()->json([
        'data' => PotonganPenggajianModel::where('nip', $id)
            ->select('jenis_potongan', 'some_field')
            ->get(),
    ]);
}
```

**JS**

```js
$('#nama').on('change', function () {
    var optionText = $("#nama option:selected").val();

    var buildHTML = function (data) {
        var html = '';

        for (i in data) {
            html += '<h3>' + data[i].jenis_potongan + '</h3>';
            // someting with data[i].some_field
        }

        return html;
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo url('/'); ?>" + "/getidpotongan/" + optionText,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#potonganku').html(buildHTML(response.data));
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: using this is solve but what if not just jenis_tunjangan in controller??

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new empty `$val = array();` array for every foreach. lets put it outside.

So your Controller would be:

```php
 public function getIDpotongan($id)
{
    $data = array();
    $list = PotonganPenggajianModel::where('nip', $id)->get();
    $val = array();
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        $val[] ='<h3> ' . "'" . $row['jenis_potongan'] . "'" . '</h3>';
        $data[] = $val;
    }
   $output = array("data" => $data);
    return response()->json($output);
}
```